# Python - Transposing a list (rows with different length) using numpy fails

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

When the list contains only rows with same length the transposition works:

```
numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).T.tolist();
>>> [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

But, in my case the list contains rows with different length:

```
numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]).T.tolist();
```

which fails. Any possible solution?

Comment: What do you imagine the output of transposing `[[1,2],[3,4,5]]` to be?

Comment: @Alec In my case for `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]`, I expect `[[1,4],[2,5],[3]]` (obviously)

Comment: is numpy a requirement?

Comment: @DavidRobertsson Of course not, any solution is welcomed.

Comment: @DimChtz Obviously that is what you want for your sample input - I was suggesting that what you want might not make sense for a lot of other inputs (including the one I suggested).

Comment: @Alec Ohh, I see what you mean. Didn't see that coming :P

Comment: For numpy arrays with rows of different lengths, the individual elements are lists, not numpy arrays.  For instance compare `J = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]); type(J[0])` with `J = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]); type(J[0])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not having `numpy` as a compulsory requirement, you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to do the transpose:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
r = [list(filter(None,i)) for i in zip_longest(*l)]
print(r)
# [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3]]
```

`zip_longest` pads the results with `None` due to *unmatching* lengths, so the list comprehension and `filter(None, ...)` is used to remove the `None` values

In python 2.x it would be [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Comment: First of all, thank you it works. One question: what `filter(None,i)` really does?

Comment: @DimChtz I've added more description

Answer (score 0):

Using all builtins...

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
res = [[] for _ in range(max(len(sl) for sl in l))]

for sl in l:
    for x, res_sl in zip(sl, res):
        res_sl.append(x)
```